# Sending JS variables with AJAX, to PHP (And using it)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am currently making a plugin for wordpress, which is ajax to send a js variable as the data. i then want to be able to use that variable from the data, in my PHP plugin template file.

So here is a more detailed desc.
i have this file called showgroups.php

```
            <?php
            foreach ($attributes as $term) :?>
                <a class="testclick" href="#" rel="<?php echo $term->term_taxonomy_id?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
                <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            var clickedID = "";
            $('.testclick').click(function(){
                clickedID = $(this).attr('rel');
                console.log(clickedID);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        data: ({clickedID: clickedID}),
                        success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

So in my PHP here i pass a an ID as a int into some HTML `<a>` tags, and i place the as the rel="" of the link.

Then in my click function i take the rel and put it into a variable->clickedID, i then send the AJAX request, where i pass the variable->clickedID into the data property.
In my success function i console.log the response of the `<a>`, and this is giving me the correct IDs (from the rels of my `<a>`'s)
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qBxC.png)

now i try to pass this data/AJAX call to my next PHP file:

```
            <?php
            $lol = $_GET['clickedID'];
            echo '123' . $lol;
```

but the $lol variable is a NULL. 
does anyone has any idea, to why i can't seem to access, the data from the AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the rel to `data-rel` HTML5 data properties ([Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp))

Updated code is as follow:

```
 <?php foreach ($attributes as $term): ?>
      <a class="testclick" href="#" data-rel="<?php echo $term->term_taxonomy_id?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            var clickedID = "";
            $('.testclick').click(function(){
                clickedID = $(this).data('rel'); // change over here
                console.log(clickedID);
                var dataString = {clickedID: clickedID}; //change over here
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", // change over here
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        data: dataString , // change over here
                        success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <?php
            foreach ($attributes as $term) :?>
                <a class="testclick" href="#" rel="<?php echo $term->term_taxonomy_id?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
                <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            var clickedID = "";
            $('.testclick').click(function(){
             var clickedID = $(this).attr('rel');
                console.log(clickedID);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        data: ({clickedID: clickedID}),
                        success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

you should to define like a variable if you want to pass in your get ajax request .